# How to start with VueJS in ES6 or Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, transpiler

I have used VueJS for about 2 years now in a strictly ES5 environment, like so:

```
new Vue('app', {
    el: '#app',
    data: function(){
       return {
         message: "hello world",
       }
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="app"> {{message}} </div>
```

What I am NOT familiar with is using Javascript's `import` and `export` methods, nor have I worked with ES6->ES5 transpilers.  What is the simplest way to get started?

**NOTE/UPDATE:**

I'm using Ubuntu Xenial.  And when trying vue-cli (I removed the deprecated `vue-cli` per docs and just installed `@vue/cli`), I get a version mismatch notice, however when I do `vue --version`, it doesn't agree with what the error says!  See this screenshot; error says vue@2.5.16 but a version check says 3.10.0.

[image: version mismatch]

Comment: Apart from gooling tutorials or following online guides, you could use `vue-cli` to to create a project from the ground up. Enable babel and typescript. Then you can inspect the project to see how it's been done.

Comment: `vue --version` shows the version of *Vue CLI*, not of Vue.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of [Vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) is very good and well documented. I'm using it a lot.

It uses Webpack to transpile the app to ES5. That's very useful because you can configure the browser support you need with [browserslist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist). If you are working like that, you can be sure that you don't add unnecessary polyfills in your build.

Of course, if vue-cli is not the right tool for your apps, you can use [webpack with babel](https://webpack.js.org/). I used it a lot before the current version of vue-cli. Webpack is well documented, updated and (nowadays) very fast to configure if you need the basic conf.

Comment: So, on your suggestion: vue-cli had problems working in Xenial, but worked to `vue create hello-world` on my Mac directly.  It was important to do an initial `npm run build` to see the full result of the `dist` folder.  Good start, thanks